# Mongoose: Enforce friendship relationship and return friends of a user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add an instance method to my User schema in mongoose that returns a collection of other users that a user is friends with.

**User Schema:**

```
var User = new Schema({
    username : String,
    password: String
});
```

**Friendship Schema:**

```
var FriendShip = new Schema({
    user_id: String,
    friend_id: String,
    accepted: Boolean
});
```

I created two methods that returns the user's friends _id

```
// Return id of users that are friends of this instance
User.methods.myFriendsId = function () {
    var friendship = this.model('Friend').find({user_id: this._id, accepted: true});
    var friends_id = {};
    for (f of friendship) {
        friends_id[friends_id.length] = f.friend_id;
    }
    return friends_id;
};

// Returns id of users that have this instance as friend
User.methods.friendOfId = function () {
    var friendship = this.model('Friend').find({friend_id: this._id, accepted: true});
    var friends_id= {};
    for (f of friendship) {
        friends_id[friends_id.length] = f.user_id;
    }
    return friends_id;
};
```

Then I have the method that should return the friends
i `.concat()` the result of both methods then try to loop through the `friends_id` to find each user.

```
User.methods.friends = function () {

    var friends_id = this.myFriendsId().concat(this.friendOfId());
    var friends = {};

    for (id of friends_id) {
        this.model('User').findById(id, function(err, user) {
            friends[friends.length] = user;
        });
    }

    return friends;
};
```

I want to get a collection of friends when i call `user.friends()` on a `user` instance.

**EDIT**

Hi @Reto, sorry for getting back to you so late, i am learning nodejs with my free time and i haven't had a lot of those.

Thank you for your recommendations, i now have an understanding of how Nodejs async calls work, i also learnt about mongodb promises and that i was not getting anything returned just by saying "variable equal to a promise". `var friends_id = User.find();`. Although i initially was trying to avoid passing a callback because i wanted to be able to call the method right in my `ejs` view which i have found to be impossible so i found better ways to pass data to my view. I have also learnt how to write better mongodb queries instead of hitting the database for each `id` in my `friends_id` array.

As you rightly pointed out i am just testing the waters with node and JavaScript, i am from a C# background. So this is what i'v done.

I have modified my `Friendship` schema to store `_id`(s)  as `ObjectId` and not `String`.

```
var Friendship = new Schema({
    user_id: Schema.ObjectId,
    friend_id: Schema.ObjectId,
    accepted: Boolean
});
```

I have gotten rid of those functions that returns `friends_id` since the call has to be asynchronous. So my `User.methods.friends` function now look like this.

```
User.methods.friends = function (callback) {
    var id = this._id;
    return this.model('Friendship').find({$or: [
        {user_id: id},    // check if id is in user_id column
        {friend_id: id}    // check if id is in friend_id column
    ]},
        function (err, friendships) {
            if (err) return err;
            var friends_id = friendships.map(function (f) {  // This forms an array of whatever you return from it.
                return (id.toString() !== f.user_id.toString()) ?
                    f.user_id : f.friend_id;  // return user_id or friend_id if it does not belong to this user.
            });
            this.model('User').find({_id: {$in: friends_id}}, callback);
        });
};
```

But i have a new problem, I am getting a `TypeError` here:

`this.model('User').find({_id: {$in: friends_id}}`.

```
if (obj && '_id' in obj) continue;
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in User
```

I  tried this in mongodb console and the users returned as expected.

```
db.users.find({_id: {$in : [
    new ObjectId("55f802d3020b2641028819ba"),
    new ObjectId("55f80281cf08f091062f9f4c")
]}})
```

I looked up this error and what i found do not apply to me. Answers were to parse `friends_id` as JSON object but no need for that since i am getting it straight from a query.

I have tried to convert the `_id`(s) `.toString()` or wrap them in `new ObjectId(_id)` but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with your approach - main issue is that you don't seem to follow the fundamental principle of node.js asynchronous execution model.
This is very different from the typical code in another programming language like Java:

```
 var friends_id = this.model('Friend').find({user_id: this._id, accepted: true});
```

this does not return a list of friends! It returns a query or promise object that you still need to execute. You will need to pass a callback method to it that will be called when the database query is finished.

You cannot write a method on a model in node.js that returns the list of friends after querying the DB synchronously. You can only write a method that takes a Callback method and returns nothing. It will then execute the callback when the DB query is finished and pass the resulting list to the callback method as parameters.

Try to dive into node.js programming with simpler examples first and make sure you fully understand how the asynchronous programming works, what callbacks are, maybe study "Promises".

Comment: Hi @Reto, thanks for your answer, i have made some progress based on your response but i have a little problem. See the question.

Comment: There is a very simple feature in mongoose called "population" that will solve your problem. With this you don't need that second query anymore